# Context timeout not working as expected in golang

Tags: go, server, timeout

Helo All,

New to golang and was debugging timeout issues in a production environment. Before making a call to the server we add a timeout of 50ms to context and fire a server call. If the response is not received within 50 ms we expect the application to move on and not wait for the response.

But while debugging, I capture the duration between we fire a server call and the response received (or error out), to my surprise the value at the time is much higher than 50 ms.

Client syntax -

```
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, e.opts.Timeout)
    defer cancel()
    fireServerCall(ctx)
..
..

def fireServerCall(ctx context:Context){
  startTime:=time.Now()
  //call to the server
  res, err:=callToServer(ctx)
  if err!=nil{
   //capture failure latency
   return ....
  }
   //capture success latency
   return ....
}
```

Has anyone ever faced any similar issue? Is this expected behaviour? How did you handle such cases?

Am I doing something incorrectly? Suggestions are welcome :)

**Edit:**

I am passing context in my original code but forgot to mention it here, just added it. That mean, I am passing the same context on which my client is waiting for server to respond within 50 ms.

Comment: Your "custom" context with timeout is not known to the HTTP server. When the timeout happens, only your context will be cancelled, but not the parent context from the request. You have to act when your context is cancelled, e.g. return an HTTP error.

Comment: Also note that the response may already be ready in a buffer which the timeout may not effect, see [Go json.NewDecoder().Decode() doesn't seem to respect context deadline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72804689/go-json-newdecoder-decode-doesnt-seem-to-respect-context-deadline/72805125#72805125)

Comment: thnx @icza, I do understand ctx will be unknown to the HTTP server but I was assuming the client would honour that timeout with 50ms i.e. even without considering whats happening at server side. For me even client honour the timeout after ~100/200 ms.

Comment: The poblem _may_ lay in the fact a context is not some sort of magical "bomb" which goes off exactly after the specified timeout and "destroys" whatever other code was doing at that time. Instead, what a context does is providing a channel wich gets written to (actually closed) but let's not digress when a context gets cancelled for whatever reason. If no code _actively_ attempts to receive from that channel at that time, nothing happens. In other words, the fact a context has been cancelled is only noticed by other code in the nearest receive on the context's channel returned by `Done`.

Comment: As a shot in the dark, imagine that `callToServer` does something beyond performing a plain context-enabled HTTP request: while the code doing that "something" is being executed, the context could be cancelled but nothing will happen until some code will actively check the status of the context. The possibilities are sheer. For instance, any blocking call such as querying a database or even writing files to a slow storage could exhibit the described behavior.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should pass created context to `fireServerCall` and `callToServer` functions
2. `callToServer` should consider passed context and monitor `ctx.Done()` channel to stop its execution accordingly

Answering to comment by @Bishnu:

> Don't think this is needed. Did a test and even without passing ctx to callToServer() it works. The behaviour is not as expected under high load. Can you kindly share some document/test what you have pointed here?

Context timeout just can't work without context passing and checking its `Done()` channel. Context is not some kind of magic — simplifying it is just a struct with `done` channel which is closed by calling cancel function or when timeout occurs. Monitoring this channel — is responsibility of the innermost function that accepts it.

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func callToServer(ctx context.Context) {
    now := time.Now()
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done(): // context cancelled via cancel or deadline
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second): // emulate external call
    }
    fmt.Printf("callToServer: %v\n", time.Since(now))
}

func callToServerContextAgnostic(ctx context.Context) {
    now := time.Now()
    select {
    case <-time.After(2 * time.Second): // emulate external call
    }
    fmt.Printf("callToServerContextAgnostic: %v\n", time.Since(now))
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()
    callToServer(ctx)

    ctx2, cancel2 := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel2()
    callToServerContextAgnostic(ctx2)
}
```

Results:

```
callToServer: 100ms
callToServerContextAgnostic: 2s
```

You can launch it on Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/tIxjHxUzYfh

Note that many of the clients (from standard or third party libraries) monitors `Done` channel by themselves.

For example standard HTTP client:

```
    c := &http.Client{} // client for all requests

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(time.Millisecond*100))
    defer cancel()

    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, "http://google.com", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    resp, err := c.Do(req) // will monitor `Done` channel for you
```

Some docs and articles:

- https://pkg.go.dev/context
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-contexts-in-go

Comment: Have updated the question, i forgot to mention it. Apologies.

Comment: @Bishnu ok, so check point 2. If `callToServer` monitors `cox.Done()` concurrently with external call — timeout will work

Comment: Don't think this is needed. Did a test and even without passing ctx to callToServer() it works. The behaviour is not as expected under high load. Can you kindly share some document/test what you have pointed here?

Comment: @Bishnu added examples to my answer